# Navigation bar with back button not hiding

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, back-button

I have an issue with my navigation bar.

The first screen of my app is a welcome screen, with two classic buttons in the center of the screen. No bars (tab or nav, and status is hidden with the setStatusBarHidden in the `viewDidLoad`). I only implemented one of the buttons but both will work the same way (the two screens are similar). So the first button loads up a "sign up" screen (a `UITableViewController`) with a form to fill in. There, the status bar is shown, and I added a navigation bar (in the attributes panel of my view controller), with a "send" button on the top right.

In the attributes panel of my "navigation item" (as it's called), I entered a name for the back button, which is correctly displayed (although I'd like to change the name, but I'll do it later).

My problem is that when I hit the back button, it takes me back to the "welcome" screen but the status bar is not hidden, there is a nav bar with no title and no buttons, and I can't find a way to hide them. I tried using `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewDidUnload` (in the sign up view) but nothing works (I can hide the status bar, but the view is loaded so there is a black space between the non-hidden nav bar and my content).

By the way, I have done most of the design using the storyboard, not with code, but I don't mind using both.

Can anybody help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hide the status bar and navigation bar in `viewWillAppear`: method and not in the `viewDidLoad`: method.If your dont want to show `status bar or navigation bar`,put that code in `AppDelegate` Class.

**Edited:**

This will hide your navigation bar in your View controller.Put it in `viewWillAppear`:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

This hides your status bar.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated: UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

Your view controller should have `wantsFullScreenLayout` set to `YES`, as well as hiding the status bar.Black space is showing your view is automatically didn't resized when you dont have `status bar or navigation bar`.you need to check auto-sizing in the storyboard "size inspector" in the right side pane tabs.

**Edit 1:**
This will hide your bars with animation:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added '[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];' in the viewWillAppear, but the problem remains. When I come back, the status bar is hidden, but it left an empty black space, and I also don't know how to hide the nav bar (didn't find any 'setNavigationBarHidden' or anything..), so my whole view is lowered...

Comment: Thanks, I'm facing another unrelated problem that I need to fix to try this. I'll give feedback and select your answer if it worked ! :)

Comment: So the main problem is gone, but it's not perfect.. lol. The back button creates a push (left to right ? like a back-slide) but just before the animation starts, the status bar and the nav bar are hidden. It's not terrible but easily noticeable. Any ideas/suggestions ? Thanks again for the quick help

Comment: The back button creates a push (left to right ? like a back-slide) means??I dont understand the issue.I think you "push" to the welcome screen again.Its not the correct way.You have to "pop" your lastview.So that it will correctly move to your old welcome screen

Comment: I did not act programmatically on the transition : I entered a name for the back button in my storyboard, and it added it automatically. So I did not choose to "push" "pop" or anything.. The transition is like the standard segue "push" but backwards (more understandable ? lol). So the issue is that the status bar and the nav bar hide right before the transition, while the view on which they appear is still on screen. Can you figure what's happening ? I'm trying to take a screenshot, but the transition is short lol

Comment: Thanks, that's what I just tried :) it's pretty good, but I can't figure out why it's not possible to make both bars stick to the "leaving" view during the transition.. Too perfectionist maybe :) Anyways I'll go with this last solution ! Thanks again for your help !